# Draw a graph in Windows Forms Application from a DataTable in a Data Access class

Tags: c#

I've done some research and I've managed to found information about drawing a graph where you hard code a Data Table with fixed values.

This is the link: [How to create chart using data table](http://www.etechpulse.com/2013/04/how-to-create-chart-using-data-table.html)

My problem is however;

I don't have a Data Table like that. I have DataAccess class that call the data from a database then stores it in a Data Table;

```
public DataTable select_top_sheep(string farmerid)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = 
                        new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 
                                         S.SheepID
                                        ,W.Weight 
                                  FROM[Farmstat_V1.0].[dbo].[Sheep] S
                                  INNER JOIN[Farmstat_V1.0].[dbo].[Weight] W 
                                    ON S.SheepID = W.SheepID 
                                  WHERE S.FarmerID = '" + farmerid + "' 
                                  ORDER BY W.Weight DESC", conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Then on my form I call this method to get the data, but how can I from here display it in a graph? I can see that the data stores successfully in the DataTable when I run the program in debug mode.

I just want to use the basic Chart tool from the toolbox to display the data graphically.

Comment: One word of advise: Please, replace in your code variable farmerid with a parameter [WHERE S.FarmerID =@farmerid],  and then add value from passed string to your SQL parameter. 
SqlCommand. Parameters.AddWithValue("farmerid", farmerid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to figure out the answer with the use of the link I provided in my question.

This is what I did;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initializes a new instance of the DataAccess class 
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();

    // The styling of the graph
    chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

    // The required lines for getting the data from the method in the DataAccess
    chart1.DataSource = da.select_top_sheep(farmerID);
    chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "SheepID";
    chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Weight";
    chart1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to google it:
[Chart sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx)

```
    public void SampleCode()
    {
        // some code
        foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables["Query"].Rows)
        {
            // For each Row add a new series
            string seriesName = row["SalesRep"].ToString();
            Chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
            Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            Chart1.Series[seriesName].BorderWidth = 2;

            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < myDataSet.Tables["Query"].Columns.Count; colIndex++)
            {
                // For each column (column 1 and onward) add the value as a point
                string columnName = myDataSet.Tables["Query"].Columns[colIndex].ColumnName;
                int YVal = (int)row[columnName];

                Chart1.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(columnName, YVal);
            }
        }

        DataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet;
        DataGrid.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I am pretty new to C# and I struggle a lot with it, so I don't really get how to use that. Because I see a DataSet there and I don't use that

Comment: If you have a DataTable then you can use the example as it is referring to the Tables in the DataSet. A DataSet is basically just a colleciotn of DataTables.